# setInterval is not working with my function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to build an analog clock.

```
second_hand = document.getElementById('second_hand');
```

I have a `function` that get the time.

```
function getTime() {
  var date = new Date(),
  second = date.getSeconds();

  return second;
}
```

Then I have a `function` that rotate the hand.

```
function rotateHand(hand) {
  var second = getTime();
  hand.style.transformOrigin = "0 100%";
  hand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + second * 6 + 'deg)';
}
```

Then I am using a `setInterval` to update my `rotateHand()` every second.

```
setInterval(rotateHand(second_hand), 1000);
```

But my hand is not updating(moving) every second. What is wrong?

Here is a version of this:

```js
second_hand = document.getElementById('second_hand');
function getTime() {
  var date = new Date(),
  second = date.getSeconds();

  return second;
}
function rotateHand(hand) {
  var second = getTime();
  hand.style.transformOrigin = "0 100%";
  hand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + second * 6 + 'deg)';
}

setInterval(rotateHand(second_hand), 1000);
```

```html
<div id="second_hand">hiiiiiiiiii</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setInterval` needs a function reference as the first parameter. You're not passing a function reference, you're invoking the `rotateHand` function.

You can either :

- pass a reference to an anonymous function that will call `rotateHand` with the secondHand parameter : `setInterval(function () { rotateHand(second_hand)}, 1000);`
- use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass a function reference to `rotateHand` with secondHand as a parameter :

```js
var second_hand = document.getElementById('second_hand');

function getTime() {
  var date = new Date(),
  second = date.getSeconds();

  return second;
}

function rotateHand(hand) {
  var second = getTime();
  hand.style.transformOrigin = "0 100%";
  hand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + second * 6 + 'deg)';
}

setInterval(rotateHand.bind(null, second_hand), 1000);
```

```html
<div id="second_hand">2nd hand</div>
```

Comment: oh hey i guess we both follow the javascript tag

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Strangely, I was testing my setInterval with another function and it was working while I was passing only the function, not a reference! Any idea why?

Comment: Doesn't `call` run the function immediately, wouldn't it make more sense to use `bind`?

Comment: @FredStark `bind` is what I meant. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited.

Comment: I'm more surprised `call` worked for the OP! haha

Comment: First version of the answer was with the anonymous function. I added the example with call/bind later.

Answer (score 2):

The issue probably has to do with this line:

```
setInterval(rotateHand(second_hand), 1000);
```

rotateHand(second_hand) evaluates to undefined. So you're setInterval isn't doing anything.

Instead try this:

```
setInterval(()=>rotateHand(second_hand), 1000);
```

Or the equivalent without arrow sugar:

```
setInterval(function(){rotatehand(second_hand)},1000);
```

Comment: That worked too. I'm not familiar with how the arrow expression works though. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an example without them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it should work:

`function(){rotateHand(second_hand);}`

`rotateHand(second_hand);` isn't a function reference so it won't work.

```js
second_hand = document.getElementById('second_hand');
function getTime() {
  var date = new Date(),
  second = date.getSeconds();

  return second;
}
function rotateHand(hand) {
  var second = getTime();
  hand.style.transformOrigin = "0 100%";
  hand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + second * 6 + 'deg)';
}

setInterval(function(){rotateHand(second_hand);}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="second_hand">------------</div>
```